Why can I cat a file I can't find?
I'm working on a TryHackMe problem (Task 15 here) to exploit a vulnerable component of a website to gain RCE and then read the contents of /opt/flag.txt.
The targeted website uses an IP generated by TryHackMe which is different on each attempt, so I can't link to it. The exploit is here.
I can read the file using cat /opt/flag.txt; but find -name 'flag.txt' and find -name '/opt/flag.txt' return no result; attempts to cd to /. or to the parent of the cwd are unsuccessful; and ls -a doesn't list flag.txt in the cwd.
Why can I cat a file that I can't find, and that doesn't appear to be in the cwd?




Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Your use of the find command was incorrect.  Here are my results:
RCE $ pwd
/htdocs/bootstrap/img

RCE $ id
uid=100(apache) gid=101(apache) groups=82(www-data),101(apache),101(apache)

RCE $ ls -ld /opt
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb  3  2023 /opt

RCE $ ls -l /opt
total 4
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            27 Feb  3  2023 flag.txt

RCE $ cat /opt/flag.txt
THM{But_[redacted]lt!}

RCE $ find / -name flag.txt 2>/dev/null
/opt/flag.txt

Here's an explanation of where you went wrong.

find -name 'flag.txt'

This doesn't return anything because find will default to the current directory.  Since flag.txt is not located in /htdocs/bootstrap/img or a directory under it, the command won't return anything. The find command functions correctly.

find / -name '/opt/flag.txt'

This returns nothing because there is no file named '/opt/flag.txt'. You need to use the -path option.

RCE $ find / -path '/opt/flag.txt'
/opt/flag.txt

